# Swiper.js Error- ReferenceError: window is not defined when installed via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify, swiper.js

When I install 3.0.3 via npm and add the line require('swiper') before defining a React.js component it blows up with with the following:

```
dist/js/swiper.js:20
  window.Swiper = function (container, params) {
  ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Of course the server doesn't have a window, but I can't figure out how to get around this error. First time diving into node. Using react, gulp, browserify, express. Any ideas?

Comment: The project doesn't appear to be properly setup to support server-side use as it's not written to support CommonJS or similar module systems like Node.js uses. It's seems likely to only be included in NPM's registry as an alternative to Bower, but is still meant to be served to the client.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you nailed it. Thanks for the help.